# Shorten or discard JOIN to middle table which we don't pull data from

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT
    ost_form_entry_values.value as ost_form_entry_values__value
FROM 
    ost_ticket AS t
LEFT JOIN ost_form_entry
    ON t.ticket_id = ost_form_entry.object_id
LEFT JOIN ost_form_entry_values
    ON ost_form_entry_values.entry_id = ost_form_entry.id
WHERE ost_form_entry_values.field_id = 20
```

In that case, the only purpose of `ost_form_entry` is to connect to `ost_form_entry_values` for the value I'm looking for.

Is there different/better way to do that so that I'm not joining in a table that I'm not referencing in the final output?

Comment: This is a very common data model in databases that follow proper normalization. Don't worry about trying to make this query better - you're doing exactly what you should be doing. __Edit:__ If you're trying to remove the middle table from your query because you're finding your queries are slow, you should make sure that you have indexes setup properly (with the appropriate columns, and column order)

Comment: Nope, was just unsure since I was joining a table I wasn't selecting from if there was a different way to do it that I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without changing the data model the answer is **no**. It's a normal thing to follow relations between tables to get the data you need.

If there's 1:1 relationship between `ost_form_entry` and `ost_form_entry_values` then you could put the object_id into the values table (that would avoid the JOIN), but I suspect that you have the so called **[Entity–attribute–value model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)** which is by the way not the best way to keep unstructured data in SQL.

**MySQL 5.7+** supports `JSON` format for example, so you could investigate that for the same purpose you are using your values table (and get rid of that table). Though, it would require the application to be adjusted in (probably) many places and if your MySQL version is older, an upgrade of the database.